# Android borderless buttons

Tags: android, view, styles

I hate to be the third person to ask this, but the previous [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855791/how-to-create-standard-borderless-buttons-like-in-the-design-guidline-mentioned) [askings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167900/how-to-create-borderless-buttons-in-android) haven't seemed to answer it fully.  The android design guidelines detail [borderless buttons](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/buttons.html), but not how to make them.  In one of the previous answers, there was a sugestion to use:

`style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless"`

This works well for a Holo theme, but I use a lot of Holo.Light as well and

`style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless"`

Does not seem to exist.  Is there a way to apply a style for such borderless buttons in Holo.Light, or better yet, simply apply a borderless tag without specifying which theme it belongs in, so the app can pick the proper style at runtime?

Holo.ButtonBar seems to fit the bill for what I am looking for, except it provides no user feedback that it's been pressed.

Also, is there a place in the documentation that lists such styles that can be applied and a description of them?  No matter how much I google, and search through the docs, I can't find anything.  There is just a non-descriptive list if I right click and edit style.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Got a perfect answer from javram, and I wanted to add some XML for anyone interested in adding the partial borders google has adopted.

Fora  horizontal divider, this works great

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_divider_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@color/holo_blue" />
```

and this for a vertical one:

```
<View
     android:id="@+id/vertical_divider"
     android:layout_width="1dip"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
     android:background="@color/holo_blue" />
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9951394/780271).  In a nutshell the correct solution is to use the following:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: @Xdg it will work if you use HolloEveywhere: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/

Comment: If you're using AppCompat library, then remove the "android:" prefix and it will work:
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"

Answer (score 47):

Simply add the following style attribute in your `Button` tag:

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#Borderless

Comment: This is a good answer, but keep in mind that the attribute was added in API 11.

Comment: And borderlessButtonStyle sets background to selectableItemBackground and sets some padding, nothing more.

Answer (score 12):

At the risk of beating a dead horse, here's another (possibly better) option. AppCompat v7 defines a borderless button style. If you're already making use of the AppCompat library, just go with that:

`<Button android:text="@string/borderlessButtonText" style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless" />`

Answer (score 8):

This code will remove all background for a button:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: That seems like an answer that is much to simple to take 3 questions to answer, but it does the trick exactly.

Also, for anyone seeing this later and wondering, to get the semi-borders google has adopted, I added some code that worked for me in the first post, since posting code in sub-responses is hard to read.

Comment: I remember thinking the same thing when I was trying to figure this one out. I am using it as a hyperlink, which should have been a relatively simple task, or so I thought...

Comment: I don't get user feedback, when pressing the borderless button. No highlight or anything. Did I miss something?

Comment: @dead I do not get the API 11 requirement. My min is set to 10.

Answer (score 1):

Just incase anybody is looking for light-weight solution to get the borderless button for the API's that do not support the Holo theme (like I did for a long time), Im posting my solution below:

```
<View 
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#505154"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Reply"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp" android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:textColor="#5c5966"
        android:text="@string/btnReplyText"/>

    <View 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:background="#505154" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp" android:layout_marginTop="7dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp" android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:textColor="#5c5966"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="@string/btnDeleteText" />

    <View 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:background="#505154"
        android:text="@string/btnReplyText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp" android:layout_marginTop="7dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Exit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/btnExitText"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp" android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:textColor="#5c5966"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

All you have to do is change the colours and text to suit your own background. All the best!