# how I get a custom button with a removed space outside corners

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml, android-drawable, android-designer

I'm using this tool https://angrytools.com/android/button/ to create custom android button and here is the drawable xml for it

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="14dp"
        android:topRightRadius="14dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/turquoise"
        />
    <size
        android:width="0dp"
        android:height="60dp"
        />
</shape>
```

[image]
but as appear in the image I make make the orange custom button over layout with a turquoise background color and above it I make another custom button with turquoise.

it appears in the corners of orange custom button there is an effect so how can I remove this effect like this image

[image]

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695115/android-borderless-buttons) I think you need to add `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"`

Comment: here is my current button but the problem not solved   
<Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_place_order"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button_red"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:text="@string/cart_button_submit"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                />

Comment: your screenshot looks fine except for the shadow, right? it it possible that you just have to define `app:elevation="0dp"` for the View that is causing the shadow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this sample

your `xml` layout file

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/turquoise_bg"
        android:layout_height="50sp"/>

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/red_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

in drawable folder
**red_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#40e0d0" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="14dp"
            android:topRightRadius="14dp" />
        <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
        <size android:height="60dp" />
    </shape>
 </item>
 </layer-list>
```

**turquoise_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="14dp"
    android:topRightRadius="14dp" />
<solid android:color="#40e0d0" />
<size android:height="60dp" />
</shape>
```