# Compound Drawable as Action in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView that implements a linear list of string items.
I want the list item to have a secondary action, 'share', to the right of **each** item. I created a compound drawable like Google suggested, in XML, but how do I access the drawable and set a `OnClickListener()` on it? Am I better off just having two elements?

Compound Drawable TextView in my list item layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:background="#101010"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />
```

Comment: Better have 2 different elements.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666174/implement-onclick-only-for-a-textview-compound-drawable

Answer (score 0):

Got some good tips but for my project in particular I found it better management to have two elements. Check out @Vishnuvathsan's answer for this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666174/implement-onclick-only-for-a-textview-compound-drawable) for the compound drawable.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:background="#101010"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/shareBtn"
    android:contentDescription="@string/action_share"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp"
    android:background="#101010"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```