# Android - Image Right of Text Overlaps Screen Horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying have an image to the right of a `TextView` with a single line.
When the text is short it works fine. The problem is when the text is too big and is truncated. The text fills the `LinearLayout` and the image is off screen

Short text:
[image: short text]

Long text:
[image: long text]

The code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivInfectedDevOtherInfoIcon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivInfectedDevOtherName"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivInfectedDevOtherName"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_tv" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When the text is long how can I make the Image dock to the right so that it does not overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make the below changes to your xml layout:

1.In **LinearLayout** add:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
```

2.In **TextView** add:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

3.In **AppCompatImageView** add:

```
android:layout_weight="0"
```

Final xml layout will be like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur "/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivInfectedDevOtherInfoIcon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivInfectedDevOtherName"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivInfectedDevOtherName"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_tv" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Result for Long Text:**

[image: long_text]

**Result for Small Text:**

[image: small_text]

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 1:** From the comments:

> This works when the text is long and is truncated. When the text is
> short the image stays docked at the right and there is a bigger gap
> then the intended 8dp between the two element

So the behavior you're looking for won't work unless the view is plugged right into the `TextView` which will measure the current width & truncates when the end is reached on the `drawable` & not text. So you can create such component or use `drawableEnd` or `drawableEndCompat`.

With `drawableEndCompat` Your layout would look like this(You can remove `LinearLayout` IMO):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:text="Lorem cd" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If you want to have a click on `drawableEndCompat` then you can look at answers on SO like this: [Implement onClick only for a TextView compound drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666174/implement-onclick-only-for-a-textview-compound-drawable)

**Example:**

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private void setOnEndClickListener() {
        TextView txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvText);
        txtview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if (event.getRawX() >= txtview.getRight() - txtview.getTotalPaddingRight()) {
                        Log.d("MG-onClick", "Drawable Clicked");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

**Old Answer:**

Add `layout_weight=1` &  `layout_width="0dp"` to your `TextView`.

So it would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivInfectedDevOtherInfoIcon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivInfectedDevOtherName"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivInfectedDevOtherName"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This works when the text is long and is truncated. When the text is short the image stays docked at the right and there is a bigger gap then the intended 8dp between the two elements

Comment: @Raimundo Try the updated answer. See if it works for you.

Comment: This ways works. But @MariosP answer also works and it suits better for my needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivInfectedDevOtherInfoIcon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ivInfectedDevOtherName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivInfectedDevOtherName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_tv" />

  </LinearLayout>
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: When the text is short the image stays docked at the right and there is a bigger gap then the intended 8dp between the two elements.

Comment: Still doesn't work. When the text is short the image stays docked to the right and it does not have the size of 40dp.
`android:layout_weight` does not seem to be the way to solve this.

Comment: You can add attribute  android:maxLength="20" in your textView Widget

Comment: But then there is some space not used to the right. And this way won't work on all screens sizes and densities.