# Android imagebutton: how to remove tinted rectangle around image?

Tags: android, imagebutton

I'm developing and Android app. I have a main menu with lots of imagebuttons, each of which takes the user to a new view on click.

The problem I'm having is that surrounding each icon is a tinted rectangle that changes to a light blue colour when tapped. How do I remove this transparent square in the .xml layout file?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Is it perhaps a standard function of Android (depending upon version)? If so then you may need to subclass Imagebutton?

Comment: maybe this link will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167900/how-to-create-borderless-buttons-in-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

they probably have the default background from the android system. to remove that, define a transparent color

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

and then use it as background in your buttons

```
<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/button"
             android:background="@color/transparent"/>
```

I think it will work the way you want

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the framework's

`android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

But for what you are trying to archive this is the **better solution**:

`android:background="@null"`

Comment: Thanks a lot. @null is better way

Answer (score 0):

I know theres now rectangle or colour, when you use your own buttons.. create, implement and use them, then you wont have the rectangle