# How to create borderless button using style from style.xml file (along with all other styles)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-button

I am trying to create a borderless button, but I also have many other styles for my button and I want to design button borderless by embedding code into my style.xml file.

One way I found was:
By using    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"    in my layout file.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />
```

But I want to make this happen in style.xml and I don't know what values does '   **_______** take?

Comment: Have you tried extending from [Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36666660/1815052)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by making Custom Button class which extend default Button class, and use this class everywhere, and second possible solution is use

If it's selected or not selected you should use a toggle button https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html

Be aware that there are still 4 states for that

You define them in a selector like this

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/likeactivepressed" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/likeinitialpressed"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/likeon"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/likeinitial"/>
</selector>
```

Then define it in your button like this

```
android:background="@drawable/like_button"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
<style name="style_name" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <!-- your style -->
</style>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.[How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167900/how-to-create-borderless-buttons-in-android) and [another](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#Borderless)

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: You should use comments to ask for clarification.

Comment: @RandallArms okay i thought i just posted an answer. I tried commenting but it needs 50 reputation to make a comment hope you know it. But in future i will keep it in mind. So i re-edited the answer now it doesn't looks like an that I am asking a clarification. Thanks !

Comment: Looks good to me now! Hope I did not come off as too pedantic.

Comment: @RandallArms its okay to stop doing mistakes when its small. So thank you.