# Set android:foreground View borderless

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How to set `android:foreground` drawable of a button borderless in Android development? Like in case of `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`.

Comment: does...setting `android:foreground` not work?  what happens when you do that, and what, specifically, did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use multiple approches

```
1. android:background="@android:color/transparent"

2. android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

3. style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

or

```
4. android:background="@drawable/btn_borderless"
```

in 4th approch you will require a xml file btn_borderless in your drawable folder such as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
</shape>
```

I got this answer from https://inducesmile.com/android-programming/how-to-create-borderless-button-in-android/

and your question may be possible duplicate of [How to create borderless button using style from style.xml file (along with all other styles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099548/how-to-create-borderless-button-using-style-from-style-xml-file-along-with-all)

Comment: In the question, I have asked if we can make foreground of the button borderless, while in answer it shows about background of the button. Prathamesh, can you please check.

Comment: Is there a way in which we can set android:foreground of button which doesnot have limit on border.

Comment: Let me try some of the things i found ,if they apply to your problem i will update my answer, by the way i have found that   android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground" can also be applicable

Comment: Problem with applying android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" is, even though my button background was oval when applying ripple on button it shows the rectangular edges.

Comment: well then try adding the code in the 4th approach of my answer just replace the "rectangle" with "oval"