# selectableItemBackground not found

Tags: android, button, background

I'm trying to set borderless background to button (and it must be highlighted when pressed). To do so I'm try to set:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

(as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855791/how-to-create-standard-borderless-buttons-like-in-the-design-guidline-mentioned))

But get error:

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '?android:attr/selectableItemBackground').
```

API level 1.6, also tried API 2.2

Answer (score 5):

This only available from API Level 11 i.e. Android 3.0

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground` is not a ressource but an attribute. You have to specify a ressource on `android:background` property.

Comment: I'm following accepted answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855791/how-to-create-standard-borderless-buttons-like-in-the-design-guidline-mentioned. See it for detailes.