# How to add bottom button fragment (animated)

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I want a OK/Cancel button on the bottom of my listview-fragment to accept/cancel. I figured that Fragments was the way to go (should even support animation).

**But I can't get it to work!** It only shows the first fragment (fragmentPlaceholder in the code)

The xml for the buttons have I gotten from this post's accepted answer:

[How to create standard Borderless buttons (like in the design guidline mentioned)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855791/how-to-create-standard-borderless-buttons-like-in-the-design-guidline-mentioned)

The code is in C# but the problem should be the same in Java. The xml for the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
            android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/ViewColorPickerHelper"
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
            android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" 
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ViewColorPickerHelper"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="Cancel" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnColorPickerOk"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="Ok" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ViewColorPickerHelper"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The xml for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/fragmentPlaceholder" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/addEventReportButtonPlaceholder"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/addEventReportProgressBar"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code that includes the fragment:

```
var newFragment = new BottomButtonsFragment ();
FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
ft.Add (Resource.Id.addEventReportButtonPlaceholder, newFragment).Commit ();
```

Where BottomButtonsFragment are:

```
public class BottomButtonsFragment : Fragment
{
    public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.BottomButtonsFragment, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the android:layout_weight of the topmost LinearLayout to much more than the one at the bottom solved the problem!