# No visible button feedback after setEnabled(false) -> (true)/ selectableItemBackground as drawable?

Tags: java, android, button

With one button i'm disabling three other button's with button.setEnabled(false).
That works fine.
When this button is pressed again, the tree button's will be enabled with button.setEnabled(true). 
They are still doing what they shoud and are fine responding to the onClickListener.
But since the enabling they do not visible respond when they get pressed.

How do i reactivate them right? 
(i already searcht in google but didn't find anything).

---

```
private void startSleeping()
{
    editorState.putBoolean("SLEEPING", true);
    editorState.commit();

    buttonDrink.setEnabled(false);
    buttonEat.setEnabled(false);
    buttonWash.setEnabled(false);
    buttonDrink.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkgray));
    buttonEat.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkgray));
    buttonWash.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkgray));
    buttonSleep.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
    buttonWash.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightgray));
    buttonDrink.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightgray));
    buttonEat.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightgray));
    buttonSleep.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(color.black));
}

private void stopSleeping()
{
    editorState.putBoolean("SLEEPING", false);
    editorState.commit();

    buttonDrink.setEnabled(true);
    buttonEat.setEnabled(true);
    buttonWash.setEnabled(true);
    buttonDrink.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
    buttonEat.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
    buttonWash.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
    buttonSleep.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
    buttonWash.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    buttonDrink.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    buttonEat.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    buttonSleep.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
}
```

---

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonEat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_size"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_size"
            android:text="@string/button_eat"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
```

[image]

Comment: put appropriate codes

Comment: i added code but don't know what that coud tell you more then i already wrote^^

Comment: Are you sure that stopSleeping() is being invoked?

Comment: 100% sure. There is no other way and the setBackground... is also visible invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are setting the background resource as transparent instead of what you applied in the layout as the background drawable to those buttons. Re-apply those background drawables and you'll get the touch feedback again. That should solve your problem.

On a side note for future implementations you can directly provide the enabled/disabled background resource in the drawable's list-selector itself. use state_enabled = true/false. This eliminates the need of doing all of that in the code.

Comment: That sounds like it makes sense but how do i re-apply the background drawables?

Comment: in your stop sleeping function instead of setBackgroundColor... do `setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourDrawableName));`

Comment: bevor you answerd i tried:
buttonDrink.setBackgroundColor(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground); But had the same effect as setting it transparent. 

But i think you get me wrong. I don't use drawables for buttons.

Comment: so what you are saying is that you were using the buttons as stock ... and only while disabling them you added background color? If you were using stock buttons then the drawable set by default already has a in-built drawable for the disabled view. So you don't need to setBackroundColor after disabling either. However if you must change it on disabling, then you must add the stock drawable back on enabling. 
`setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_default);`

Comment: Not exactly as stock. I changed something (that i don't know anymore) so that the bottons have no surrounding. 
I've setted the backgroundDrawable with btn_default and yes there is a touch feedback. But it looks like a button on my original button.
Oh man, why didn't i documented what i did with this buttons... :/ 
But thanks that you are trying to help me anyway... :)

Comment: pass `android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground` to `setBackgroundDrawable` not to `setBackgroundColor`. That will do it. Bear in mind this was added in API level 11, won't work with with versions below that.

Comment: I'm working with API 14 so this is no problem. 
But setBackgroundDrawable just accepts drawables and attr.slectableItemBackground isn't a drawable (i belive).
I tried using it as a drawable resource but then the app is crashing (eventually because it isn't a drawable).
Edit: oh no... the description tells me that it is a drawable:
"public static final int selectableItemBackground 
Added in API level 11 
Background drawable for standalone items that need focus/pressed states. "

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#selectableItemBackground - documentation says it's a drawable. Why not just create your drawable if the framework's resource is not working, there would be no point of discussion then. -> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Comment: I was doing the buttons like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855791/how-to-create-standard-borderless-buttons-like-in-the-design-guidline-mentioned