# alignParentBottom not used

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I had a layout which used `LinearLayouts` instead of `RelativeLayouts`.  I want to add the borderless buttons to my layouts as shown here: [How to create standard Borderless buttons (like in the design guidline mentioned)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8855791/2442638)

So, to use this, I had to change my `LinearLayouts` to `RelativeLayouts`. This has worked fine for the most part.  However, when I try to use the alignParentBottom for one of the RelativeLayouts it doesn't work - it just overlaps with one of my other buttons.

[image]

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".xxx" >

        <com.xxx.xxx.customedittext
            android:id="@+id/qn_et_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/delete"
            android:hint="@string/qn_et_title_hint"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" />

        <com.xxx.xxx.customedittext
            android:id="@+id/qn_et_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/qn_et_title"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/delete"
            android:hint="@string/qn_et_body_hint"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/qn_cb_ongoing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/qn_et_body"
            android:text="@string/qn_cb_ongoing" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/qn_b_create"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/qn_cb_ongoing"
            android:text="@string/qn_b_create" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
                android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/ViewColorPickerHelper"
                android:layout_width="1dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
                android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/BtnColorPickerCancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ViewColorPickerHelper"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:text="@android:string/cancel" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/BtnColorPickerOk"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ViewColorPickerHelper"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:text="@android:string/ok" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

EDIT: This is updated code. The `ScrollView` overlaps the 48dp `RelativeView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".QuickNoteFragment" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="false" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/qn_et_title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/qn_et_title_hint"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/qn_et_body"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/qn_et_title"
                android:hint="@string/qn_et_body_hint"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/qn_cb_ongoing"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/qn_et_body"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/qn_cb_ongoing" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
            android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/ViewColorPickerHelper"
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
            android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/qn_b_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ViewColorPickerHelper"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="@android:string/cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/qn_b_create"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ViewColorPickerHelper"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="@string/qn_b_create" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That behavior it's normal. The root RelativeLayout has it's bottom right after the `qn_b_create` button so aligning to bottom the last `RelativeLayout` will make them overlap. Try to use `android:fillViewport="true"` on the `ScrollView` to make it fill the screen. Also, it makes sense to put in the `ScrollView` only the content part and not the bottom buttons otherwise those will disappear from the screen when the content is big(and I don't think you want that).

Comment: @Luksprog Thanks! Worked very nicely

Comment: @Luksprog When I do that, the ScrollView overlaps with the RelativeLayout aligned at the bottom.

Comment: Check the rules you use. As the root you'll have a RelativeLayout(where's the current `ScrollView`). Then the RelativeLayout with height 48dp will be aligned to the parent's  bottom(put it first in the xml definition). Then the ScrollView with the content will have the rules:layout_alignParentTop and layout_above the previous RelativeLayout(the one with the 48 dp).

Comment: @Luksprog Sorry, I don't fully understand. I have added more recent code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following properties on the `ScrollView`:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/bottom" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <!-- rest of the code -->
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        <!-- rest of the code -->
    </ScrollView>
<RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Solved the problem entirely.  And also thanks to @Luksprog for first helping me in the comments :-)