# Making a android button’s background translucent,

Tags: android, xml

Is there a way to make an android button’s background translucent within ***xml*** code,
So the button has no background drawable?

Comment: set it to null in xml

Comment: This has been asked previously, see this answer for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/11279046/2333395

Comment: @Pulkit Sethi: i'm getting an error on that

Comment: please for the love of god look up the word translucent.

Comment: I think you mean transparent. Translucent is different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

You can also set your own colors:

```
android:background="#80000000"
```

The first two hex characters represent opacity. So #00000000 would be fully transparent. #80000000 would be 50% transparent. #FF000000 is opaque.

The other six values are the color itself. #80FF8080 is a color I just made up and is a translucent sort of pinkish.

Answer (score 0):

Set the background to the standard android transparent color.

In Code:

```
myButton.setBackground(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

In xml:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a selector.

Comment: I got a grey background,