# Defining interface in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

To develop these kind of layout, is it good to use Relativelayout?, if i use relative layout does it fit well in all devices?,

Any alternative example or sample layouts?. Suggest best way to implement this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should make a custom view for this interface for reuse. A nest of Relative and Linear layouts should do the job.
LinearLayout1(horizontal)--->image,LinearLayout2,button
LinearLayout2(vertical)--->vertical texts

Also you might be interested in [borderless buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855791/how-to-create-standard-borderless-buttons-like-in-the-design-guidline-mentioned)