# Android Borderless Button: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/button_pressed'

Tags: android, button, android-widget, android-custom-view, borderless

My application supports a minimum of API 8 (platform version 2.2). But borderless buttons require API 11. So when I try to make a button like:

```
             <button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="displayText"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" ></button>
```

Reference: [Borderless button subsection in this developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html)

I get an error **?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle requires API level 11 (current min is 8)**

I have the support library **`android-support-v4.jar`** in the `libs` folder of my project. So I removed the android namespace and changed it to `style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` (suggested in some comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855791/how-to-create-standard-borderless-buttons-like-in-the-design-guidline-mentioned)) and now I get this error:
**No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '?attr/borderlessButtonStyle').**

I could not either find a "BorderlessButtonStyle" mention, or even that of a "button" in [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.style.html), or [this](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) document?

What should I do? Which support library should I use?

---

**EDIT 1** On suggestion by @NaveenTamatar in the comment:

> res/drawable/selector_transparent_button.xml

**Problem 1:-**

Attribute "exitFadeDuration" is only used in API level 11 and higher (current min is 8)

So I tried this with a slight change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#227EC9" ></item>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#227EC9"></item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#ADADAD"></item>
    <item android:color="#2E2E2E"/>
</selector>
```

in a file named `selector_transparent_button.xml` in `res/drawable/` (I created drawable directory myself, those like drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi were there but no drawable, a quick web search revealed I could create it, if this matters at all).

**Problem 2:-**

**error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/button_pressed').**

**error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/button_focused').**

**error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/button_default').**

Comment: "But borderless buttons require API 11" -- no, `?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle` requires API Level 11. That is a specific technique for creating borderless buttons. "Which support library should I use?" -- none of them, as none of them provide a theme backport. Set your own button background that supports various states and does not have a border. You are welcome to trace through the resources for some platform level 11+ to see what background is used by `?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle`.

Comment: ... Does it necessarily have to be a `Button`? Do you know you can use a `TextView` (which is a **clickable** View)?

Comment: @DerGolem Yes, but onclick event handling for button is cleaner than that of textview. I will have to do that if this does not work. But why doesn't this work? Secondly I am not sure if `TextView` will allow an image.

Comment: res/drawable/selector_transparent_button.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
         android:drawable="@color/blue" />

   <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar What?

Comment: create res/drawable/selector_transparent_button.xml this xml file in drawable folder and use it

Comment: @CommonsWare " trace through the resources for some platform level 11+..." - I just checked the `styles.xml` in the `values - v14` `res` directory in my project, and all that contains is one `style` tag with nothing: `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>` Sorry, did I do it wrong?

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar: A State-List selector is a nice idea.

Comment: @Zarah: `onclick event handling for button is cleaner than that of textview` ... why? you can define an onClick handler in the very same way (I have a **single** onClick handler **I assign in xml** to Buttons, TextViews, ... indifferently).

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar `Attribute "exitFadeDuration" is only used in API level 11 and higher (current min is 8)` in the res/drawable/selector_transparent_button.xml file

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, I meant setting it clickable and all is a bit messy with the `ClickableSpan` and all.