# Show four button in same line without any space between them?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have four button under action bar like this. But the problem is I can not remove the space between the buttons. I used negative margin but it does not look like this. So my question is how can I achieve this design?
[image: desired design]

I did so far

```
    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sports"
        android:id="@+id/sports"
        android:layout_marginRight="-8dp"/>
    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Political"
        android:id="@+id/political"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sports"/>
```

and the output is 
[image]

Comment: Your actual output is extremely small, and it looks like there is no gap between them (only button bevel). Please add a bigger image of what you are getting now, and clarify whether you are trying to remove a gap, ore create a flat button (no bevel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add to buttons borderless style.

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

It is a default system style, that using in themes, to create button bars.

Without it, always will be a small margin. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11279046/4671372), and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#Borderless), from official documentation. It allows you to create button bars, like in your screenshot.

Comment: Can you suggest me how can I do this in api level 9. It requires minimum api level 11

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23206191/4671372) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14663170/4671372) way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
Put all your buttons within Horizontal linear layout and set the width and height as follows,

```
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use linear layout for view button in same line. Using layout_weight