# How to display background of a Button and remove 'borderless' warning?

Tags: android, xml, button

I have the following `Button` in my app:

[image: Button as it's meant to be]

Described by this code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:text="@string/next_question" />
```

But I was getting the following **warning**:

> Buttons in button bars should be borderless; use style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" (and ?android:attr/buttonBarStyle on the parent)

So I inserted this line (as [advised here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12021788/5559342)) :

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

Now the background of the button vanished.

[image: Button after background vanished]

How to **keep the first appearance removing the warning** I was getting?

Comment: If you click on the line with the warning in your xml file, press `Alt` and `Enter`, you should have an option called `Disable inspection` or `Supress:...`.

Comment: @Amylinn is that really the only option I have? I would like to find a way to fix the problem before considering to totally ignore it.

Comment: If all u want is to show a text with a background color, why use a button. Button extends text view. The only extra stuff the button has is the inbuilt background click effects(elevation on click etc). If you dont want that, use a textview instead and you wont see any more working. This warning is correct...

Comment: @amalBit that's the point: I want that! I need a *Button*. (With click effect included).

Comment: The warning should be irrelevant if you already achieved the layout you want - it simply tells you, that you are (maybe) violating the design guidelines. Have you tried to follow what the warning suggests? How did that look?