# make my button style like the AlertDialog button Style

Tags: android

I want to make my buttons style like the following 
[image]

I want to implement these buttons with my custom view I mean without using the AlertDialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do it with xml, like this:

Put this in drawable/border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#000000" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#333333"/>
</shape>
```

And then in your layout file:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    ... />
```

Then you can just set your width & height to make it look great! :)

Edit:
I would recommend to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735423/alertdialog-style-buttons-for-an-activity/18321501#18321501) answer instead thought, much more better to use built-in Android-resources.

Comment: it is near to the image but the color of background is not black

Comment: Yeah but you can change the background color to whatever you want. Just change the hex color here: <solid android:color="#000000" />

Answer (score 52):

If you prefer to use standard android attributes, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735423/alertdialog-style-buttons-for-an-activity/18321501#18321501).

In short, for your buttons set `style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"` and put them in a `LinearLayout` that has `style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"`.

Comment: This is the most correct answer. Attribute buttonBarButtonStyle is in holo theme (not sure about previous) set to borderlessButtonStyle which is what OP is after. +1

Comment: unfortunately this requires API 11.

Comment: This does not look like the Alert Dialog.  There are no dividers, above buttons or in middle of buttons

Comment: I suggest dropping the `android:` to use the AppCompat styles. Not sure if they are any different from `?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle`, but there's also `?attr/buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle`, `?attr/buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle` and `?attr/buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle`.